# Como contar errores en una dirección URL usando expresiones regulares

Tags: python, regex, diccionarios

Con la librería estándar de Python que trata Expresiones Regulares (re), utilizando el patrón de ejemplo de URL's.

```
regex = re.compile(
        r'^(?:http|ftp)s?://' # http:// or https://
        r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|[A-Z0-9-]{2,}\.?)|' #domain...
        r'localhost|' #localhost...
        r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})' # ...or ip
        r'(?::\d+)?' # optional port
        r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Ahora, ¿cómo cuantificar los errores una dirección url de entrada a partir de este patrón? Con esta librería se define un patrón de expresiones, y se conoce si es correcta o no, pero el punto es la cantidad de errores.

En este patrón las dos partes esenciales son:

1. El protocolo de comunicación.
2. EL nombre del domino o la dirección IP

Y los elementos opcionales que son el puerto.

Un ejemplo del conteo de errores:

```
url = 'ttps://www.googlecom'
```

En este caso son dos errores el protocolo y en la definición del dominio.

otro ejemplo es:

```
url = 'google.com'
```

En este caso se cuenta un error porque no se coloca el protocolo, nótese que 'www' esta ausente en el dirección URL, pero como en el patrón se definió de manera opcional no se considera un error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una posible solución es crear un diccionario con las "patterns" de dominio y de protocolo y evaluar independiente cada "pattern" para ver si coincide con la URL introducida. El resultado se guardaría en un diccionario de error (error_dict):

```
import re
pattern_dict = {
    'protocol' : r'(?:http|ftp)s?:\/\/.*?',
    'domain': r'(.*?\/\/)?(((www.)?.*?\.\w{2,3})|(localhost)|\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(:\d*)?(\/.*?)?$'
}

error_dict = {}
url = 'https://www.google.com'
for local_key in pattern_dict:
    # Set to 1 if error detected, 0 otherwise
    error_dict[local_key] = 1 if(re.compile(pattern_dict[local_key], re.IGNORECASE).match(url) == None) else 0

print error_dict
```

En este caso el resultado sería {'domain': 0, 'protocol': 0} dado que no hay errores. Si modificas la URL por 'ttps://www.googlecom' el resultado será {'domain': 1, 'protocol': 1}.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Comment: Me sirvió como base para mi problema, te lo agradezco.

Comment: Te agradezco que me expliques la expresión regular. (Especificamente `:\/\/.*?` y `(.*?\/\/)`)

Comment: Buenas, 

Para la expresión :\/\/.*? la primera parte es para buscar '://'. En las expresiones regulares,  para buscar una barra '/'  tienes que poner '\/'. Después, la parte '.*?' significa que puede haber cualquier tipo de texto o dígitos o no haber nada, (esto se consigue con el símbolo de interrogación).  
La segunda expresión (. *? \/\/) es similar a la primera: significa que puede haber escrita cualquier cosa seguida de '//'. Mira la web https://regexr.com,  te explica muy bien que quiere decir cada una de las partes.